# How to pipeline amqp queues with spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I'm used to camel, where it is somewhat simple to pipeline output from one element to the input of another.
I want to send all application events to an AMQP queue, the fire hose, and then route events to different queues depending on the event type. For example, if the event type is session.created I'd like to take it out from the fire hose and send it to the session.created queue.

I have defined the following raabitmq configuration

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost"/>

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate"  connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

<rabbit:queue name="q.firehose"/>

<rabbit:queue name="q.session.created"/>

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="e.firehose">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding key="firehose" queue="q.firehose"/>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>

<rabbit:headers-exchange name="e.router">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="q.session.created">
            <rabbit:binding-arguments>
                <entry key="x-match" value="all"/>
                <entry key="event_type" value="session.created"/>
            </rabbit:binding-arguments>
        </rabbit:binding>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:headers-exchange>
```

And I want to try something like this spring integration configuration:

```
<int:channel id="fromFirehose"/>
<int:channel id="toRouter"/>

<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="fromFirehose" queue-names="q.firehose" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

<!-- Some config element here to move all input from the firehose out and put it into e.router--/>

<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="toRouter" exchange-name="e.router"  amqp-template="routerTemplate" />
```

Which component is best suited to move input from the fire hose into the e.router exchange? Is this a good approach?
Looks like a transformer can move from messages from one channel to the other but you are obliged to apply a transformation. If there is no other way, is it there a DoNothingTransformer available?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just link both inbound and outbound adapters to the same channel.

For example:

```
<int:channel id="fromFirehose"/>
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="fromFirehose" queue-names="q.firehose" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="fromFirehose" exchange-name="e.router" amqp-template="routerTemplate" />
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample?

Comment: @dcerecedo Edited with one